# HTML5 Audio Player with Flash Fallback - error in Flash version when firing too soon?

Tags: jquery, flash, html, audio, fallback

I want to use this great little audio player on a website: http://www.brianhadaway.com/html5-audio-player-with-flash-fallback/

It is working fine for me in HTML5: http://carolineelisa.com/audiotest/

But when I force the Flash player to be used (`var isFlash = true;` in http://carolineelisa.com/audiotest2/js/jquery.audiocontrol.js) then I get a File not found error on first load: http://carolineelisa.com/audiotest2/

The button then works after that, so perhaps the following is not working because the Flash player is not ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).audiocontrol();
$(‘.audioButton’).click();
});
```

Any tips for waiting for the Flash player before 'clicking' the button (if indeed this is the problem) would be fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note these two lines in jquery.audiocontrol.js.

```
91. addListeners(window);
92. audio.playFlash(currentTrack + options.defaultMediaExtension);
```

in **addListeners** function three event handlers are being added which are meant for html5 audio, but here **window** is being passed to that function. As a result event listeners are getting added for window. Then **audio.playFlash** causes an error as the player is not ready like you have mentioned. But this error invokes **onError** function and it shows the error message written for html5audio element.

EDIT:
I explored the code further and found out that it is happening because of the following code in the index page, line 12

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).audiocontrol();
    $('.audioButton').click();
});
```

Triggering of the click event results in immediately playing the audio, which will work only for html5 audio. It takes a few seconds to embed the swf as swfobject.js is loaded dynamically. So this code should be like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).audiocontrol( { readyCallback:function(){ $('.audioButton').click();  } } );
});
```

and in jquery.audiocontrol.js, after line 125 add  ( for html5 audio)

```
if(options.readyCallback){
    options.readyCallback.call();
}
```

and in line 136, pass it as the callback function of embedSWF. The last parameter of embedSWF is a callback function which will be invoked when the SWF is ready,

```
swfobject.embedSWF(options.flashAudioPlayerPath, options.playerContainer, 
                 "0", "0", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", false, false, 
                 {id:options.flashObjectID}, options.readyCallback);
```

EDIT:
Don't know why the external interface function is not available even after getting ready callback.  I doubt its because of the 0 width and 0 height. Anyway giving the function loadFlash (line 141) as given below fixed the issue. Its working now.

```
function loadFlash() {
    swfobject.embedSWF(options.flashAudioPlayerPath, options.playerContainer, 
             "1", "1", "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", false, false, 
             {id:options.flashObjectID}, 
             function(){
        if(options.readyCallback){
            setTimeout(options.readyCallback, 150);
        }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks Diode, but when I comment out those two lines the button doesn't work at all...

Comment: In fact the those events were needed for toggling the play button. I have modified my answer with the right solution.

Comment: The external interface function playFlash is still invisible. Fixed by giving a timeout. Please see the modified answer

Comment: Wow Diode, I really appreciate your time on this. But I'm afraid I still get an error: 'There was an error loading this file' -  http://carolineelisa.com/audiotest4 (Although refreshing the page then plays the sound fine)

Comment: No problem. Please try increasing the delay, because it worked for me.

`setTimeout(options.readyCallback, 350);`